# Whats the best gui tool for mysql on mac os lion

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have mysql (latest) installed on my mac lion. I can see in the settings that its installed. but i am unable to view the content ilke i can view using the Sqlite DataBase Browser. Please suggest some good software to view using gui tool. Also suggest tool which i can use to view mysql Database on ec2 ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) is what I use on windows and linux, but they have a Mac version as well.

Comment: One problem that see often with Workbench on OS X is - it freezes a lot

Answer (score 17):

[Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is a very competent MySQL GUI for mac.

You can also provide your ec2 .pem-file for ssh login, if you want.

Answer (score -2):

If you have PHP installed on your mac you can use phpmyadmin
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: Last time i installed lamp on server (ec2) i messed up my Apache settings. I want to stay away from php. Any other alternative?

Comment: phpmyadmin is **not** a client, it is a webapp